# Object Properties are being changed after adding properties

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

A WebTable object is added.Then in the OR I decided to add 'name' property.After adding 'name' property,if I select the object and try to highlight ,it is not able to recognize the WebTable into application.On the same time all other properties are removed/refreshed from the 'Add Properties' box.I am using UFT 11.5

Why this is happening?What is the solution

Answer (score 1):

What value does the **name** property have in the object's description?

The add/remove properties dialog tries to fetch the current values from the web application. If the test object cannot be found (the browser isn't open or is on another page) it will not be able to do so and will supply blank values for any property it hasn't already saved. If this happens, and your `WebTable` object has a non-blank **name**, UFT will not be able to identify the object.

What you should do is spy on the `WebTable` in question and update the **name** property in the object repository with the correct **name**.